# Count amount of time a certain cell name appears in cell array [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab

Lets say I have the cell array

```
Z = {'Pizza' 'Hamburger' 'Hamburger' 'Sushi' 'Bacon' 'Hamburger'}
```

I want to count the amount of time a certain cell name appears,
so the output should be something like

```
Pizza = 1
Hamburger = 3
Sushi = 1
Bacon = 1
```

is there a way to do this with BASIC (or easily understandable) syntax? I'm extremely new to this so please explain your answer, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to identify the unique words in your array and count their occurrences, printing the results to the console with [`fprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html).

For example:

```
Z = {'Pizza' 'Hamburger' 'Hamburger' 'Sushi' 'Bacon' 'Hamburger'};

% Get unique words & their indices in Z
[words, ~, wordidx] = unique(Z);

% Sum occurrences of indices to get count for each word
wordcounts = accumarray(wordidx, 1);

% Loop and print
for ii = 1:numel(words)
    fprintf('%s = %u\n', words{ii}, wordcounts(ii))
end
```

Which prints:

```
Bacon = 1
Hamburger = 3
Pizza = 1
Sushi = 1
```

Note that `unique` is case sensitive, if mixed cases are possible you should normalize your array of strings with something like [`lower`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lower.html) to avoid issues with the count.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`categorical`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/categorical.html) to convert your cell array of characters to a finite set of discrete categories. Afterwards, you can use [`histogram`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) to count how often each category occurs:

```
Z = {'Pizza' 'Hamburger' 'Hamburger' 'Sushi' 'Bacon' 'Hamburger'};
Z_ = categorical(Z);
h = histogram(Z_);
h.Categories % the different categories
h.Values % the number of occurrence
```

**Alternative 1: histcounts**

If you are not interested in the plot, you can use [`histcounts`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) instead.

```
[N,categories] = histcounts(Z_);
```

**Alternative 2: summary**

If you are only interested to print the result to the screen, you can use [`summary`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/summary.html) instead of `histogram`:

```
summary(Z_);
```